# How to send SOAP message with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

Im trying to send a predefined soap message to a server using asp.net and c#

I have a known good soap message that i can send with the software tool soapUI.

i have tried for about 3 weeks to form the xml message within c# or asp.net and it does not work.

I have constructed a POST method with various attribute types, authentication password etc, thats all there, but the problem is either the creation of the final string of xml, where it says the first character in the name cannot be '<' which is how the string starts; or, when i create the page using literals and it does get sent i get the server error 500, and in that server it tells me it couldnt create the xml.

In the debugger, i break at the POST command and look at the string literal its about to send,  right click, carefully go into the message and click XML visualizer, it says it cannot show the xml document because of something not being formatted right.

I have searched for similar posts and read that xml is very strict, it has to have ...? something formatted perfectly.

One question is how to take a pre-generated soap, which is just an xml page wrapped in soap, and POST it to the server endpoint?  why is this impossible??

Why is THIS impossible: In my asp.net project, click on Add new item, select xml document, paste the known good SOAP, save it as xmldocument1, then in the code say POST(xmldocument1)  ???

Problem there is the project cannot see the xmldocument1.  Its in the project but i could not find out how to reference it or use it.

What i hoped to do is this:   sorry, the code simply doesnt show up...

original soap document -

change it to -
                     public static int value1 = 1000;

i have a known good "template" and only need to change a total of 3 variable values.

this was already done in Perl running under linux and it works perfectly, can anyone suggest how this might be done in asp.net?

Comment: Do you have a wsdl? If so, did you try to add a service reference?

Comment: no, i dont have a wsdl, but was wondering if i need to create one.  i can find a similar kind of wsdl, but when trying to make a service reference i think it had errors

Comment: ok its solved.  in the visual studio, add an xml file and save it.  then go to the project properties page and add a resource under resources tab, default seems to be none.  browse and find the new xml file click add/save.  now back in the .cs code you can see and instantiate or read from it as a string.